# What’s the best way to get the file size?

Tags: python, filesize

There are actually three ways I have in mind to determine a files size:

1. open and read it, and get the size of the string with len()
2. using *os.stat* and getting it via *st_size* -> what should be the "right" way, because it's handled by the underlying OS
3. *os.path.getsize* what should be the same as above

So what is the actual *right* way to determine the file size? What is the worst way to do it?
Or doesn't it even matter, because at the end it is all the same?

(I can imagine the first method having a problem with really large files, while the two others have not.)

Comment: I would exclude the first one, the other 2 are both ok IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first method would be a waste if you don't need the contents of the file anyway.  Either of your other two options are fine.  `os.path.getsize()` uses `os.stat()`

From genericpath.py

```
def getsize(filename):
    """Return the size of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
```

### Edit:

In case it isn't obvious, `os.path.getsize()` comes from genericpath.py.

```
>>> os.path.getsize.__code__
<code object getsize at 0x1d457b0, file "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 47>
```

Comment: nice, I thought that this could be actually the way os.getsize was implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1 is the slowest way possible. Don't use it unless you will need the entire contents of the file as a string later.

Methods 2 and 3 are the fastest, since they don't even have to open the file.

Using `f.seek(os.SEEK_END)` and `f.tell()` requires opening the file, and might be a bit slower than 2&3 unless you're going to open the file anyway.

All methods will give the same result when no other program is writing to the file. If the file is in the middle of being modified when your code runs, seek+tell can sometimes give you a more up-to-date answer than 2&3.

Answer (score 3):

Number 1 is definitely the worst. If at all, it's better to seek() and tell(), but that's not as good as the other two.

Number 2 and number 3 are equally OK, IMO. I think number 3 is a bit clearer to read, but that's negligible.

Comment: so the two others are the __right__ methods? or is there even another better solution?

Comment: I prefer os.path.getsize since it's more readable. What it does internally is exactly calling os.stat() and then fetching st_size.

Comment: One more thing about *any* option involving opening the file: if you don't have read permissions to a file those options will fail, while the os.stat() variants will succeed.

Comment: I didnt even thought about this read permissions. Thank you. So this is a bonus. But I dont have any case in mind where I want to know about the filesize without even having reading persmission. (maybe some statistics program ...)