# Why does the size of any HTML page become 6 bytes greater after saving it to a file?

Tags: python, linux, get, filesize

I use Python's [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to download HTML pages.
For each URL I execute this statement `response = requests.get(URL)`,
so the result of any GET request is written to the response variable.

I execute this statement to find out the number of bytes of the downloaded HTML page: `len(response.text)`. My idea is to only save an HTML to the hard drive if there isn't any page with the same name on my hard drive or if there is a page with the same name, but the sizes are different. I execute `Path(filepath).stat().st_size` to find the size of the file on my hard drive if the file exists. The problem arises here.

For some reason, for any downloaded page, the size of the file is always 6 bytes greater than the result of a call to the `len()` function with the `text` attribute of the `response` object. If `len()` returns 7282, then `st_size` is 7288; if `len()` returns 7216, then `st_size` is 7222 and so on. I don't understand the reason of such behavior. I could add 6 bytes to the result of `len()` to compare the sizes. I guess, it'll work, but then I won't know the actual reason. It seems like a hack.

I tried to use `curl` command to download the page, the result is the same. Magical 6 bytes are added. I've checked 10 different pages, the difference of 6 bytes stays the same.

Comment: Did you try to diff them? Also, try providing a [example] (along with a specific sample URL) so we can reproduce your results.

Comment: This *sounds* like a question that has been asked hundreds of times before. Isn't there a canonical duplicate?

Comment: Related: *[What’s the best way to get the file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776425/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-filesize)*. Though they don't mention any discrepancy.

Comment: A hex dump of the beginning of one of the files might also [be revealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte-order_marks_by_encoding).

Comment: Can you provide more details, please? E.g., sample URLs. The operating system is [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), but what edition and version, file system type (where the downloaded files are stored), etc.?

Comment: How many lines are in those downloaded HTML files? Six lines?

Comment: Related: *[File size changes after read/write txt file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273932/file-size-changes-after-read-write-txt-file-in-python)*

Comment: Related: *[File size difference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455460/file-size-difference-python)*

Comment: This question is already answered. The pages have different sizes. And they are relatively large. I didn't consider the situation that the `response.text` returns the number of characters, but not the number of bytes. All the pages that I've loaded probably have several common non-ascii characters, which describes the constant difference between the number of bytes and the number of characters for each page.

Answer (score 3):

Try saving the file in binary mode `wb` using `response.content` instead of `response.text`. This avoids any newline conversions and should not add any extra bytes for encoding:

```py
with open(filepath, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Compare the file size now to see if the discrepancy persists.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I didn't know about the `response.content` attribute and the difference with `response.text`. I've upvoted your answer, thank you! But as there is more full answer, I'll mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: @snailontheslope: But that other answer is likely a completely bogus answer (a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) hallucination).